# How do I scrape HTML using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I am not able to scrap the price of the product and the output which I get is as follow for each price:

```
<div class="pu-final">
  <span class="fk-font-17 fk-bold">Rs. 1999</span>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,e1f"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".gu4,.browse-product").each do |item|
  title = item.at_css(".fk-display-block,.title").text
  puts title
  puts "================="
  price = item.at_css(".pu-final")
  puts price
end
```

Comment: Why did you close the post? I was writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same code with a small change and it worked fine. Give it a go.

change

```
price = item.at_css(".pu-final")
```

to

```
price = item.at_css(".pu-final").text unless item.at_css(".pu-final").nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<div class="pu-final">

                    <span class="fk-font-17 fk-bold">Rs. 1999</span>
</div>
eotl

doc.at_css('div.pu-final > span.fk-font-17.fk-bold').class
# => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at_css('div.pu-final > span.fk-font-17.fk-bold').text 
# => "Rs. 1999"
```

`doc.at_css('div.pu-final')` will give you [**`Nokogiri::XML::Node`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) . Then you have to use [**`Nokogiri::XML::Node#text()`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text) to get the text value inside the element.

**Using XPATH**

```
doc.xpath("normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'pu-final')]/span[contains(@class,'fk-font-17')])")
# => "Rs. 1999"
```

**Full code**

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,e1f"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css("div.pu-details.lastUnit").each do |dv|
  product_name = dv.at_css('div.pu-title a').text.strip
  product_price = dv.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[contains(@class,'pu-final')]/span)").to_s
  print product_name,"  <----->  ",product_price,"\n"
end
```

**output**

```
Fila Storm Zender Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 1819
Puma Future Cat M1 Big 102 O Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 3849
Fila Filamotor V4 Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 1449
Adidas Volantis Hiking Shoes  <----->  Rs. 2999
Fila Varsity Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 1249
Puma Evo Speed F1 Low BMW Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 2609
Lee Cooper Running and Walking Shoes  <----->  Rs. 1329
Lee Cooper Running and Walking Shoes  <----->  Rs. 1329
United Colors of Benetton Sneakers  <----->  Rs. 2799
United Colors of Benetton Party Wear Shoes  <----->  Rs. 2449
Timberland 6 In Premium Boots  <----->  Rs. 8490
Timberland Ek Mid Boots  <----->  Rs. 8490
Clarks Montacute Lord Boots  <----->  Rs. 3249
Clarks Latch Mast Corporate Casuals  <----->  Rs. 1999
Levi's Boots  <----->  Rs. 2999
```

Comment: I tried it but it is giving same value for all the products,how it get it bind to specific product that it the price get printed simultaneous to the product name.

Comment: @shamshul2007 same value means? Can you give the more relevant part of HTML ? The html you have given,according to that my answer will work for you..

Comment: I want to scrap the page http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,e1f     and the output should be like  Product name=Price of the product

Comment: I think this is a wrong answer as it would match any text element enclosed in the `div` tag, not just of *"fk-font-17 fk-bold"* class.

Comment: @shamshul2007 so you want product name and its price .. that's it right?

Comment: @DavidUnric Don't shout as a wrong answer,when the html content is being displayed in the post very clear... There can be several format of HTML,but you should code as per the html you do have.. That's a basic understanding...

Comment: @Babai yes i want product name and its price and later on i have to scrap the image of the product  and the product URL